# Using different colors in Matlab

Tags: matlab, colors

In a 3D scatter graph of MATLAB I have 15 different clusters of data that I want to highlight. I can see MATLAB has 8 specific colors. Is there any other way I could use 7 more colors just to distinguish the clusters?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the *color* property using *set*. You must first get a handle *h* to the drawing objects and `set(h,'color',[0.2 0.3 0.9])`. The color is rgb ranging from 0 to 1 for each channel.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to use this File Exchange submission - [Generate maximally perceptually-distinct colors](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29702-generate-maximally-perceptually-distinct-colors)

It allows you to create a colormap with very distinguished colors and apply them with [COLORMAP](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/colormap.html) function. See help for this submission for more options.

```
colors = distinguishable_colors(n_colors);
```

For 3D scatter you can use this colors as an argument (C) in [SCATTER3](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/scatter3.html):

```
scatter3(X,Y,Z,[],colors)
```

To use this colors for different lines set them as default color order either for current figure:

```
set(gcf,'DefaultAxesColorOrder',colors)
```

or all figures:

```
set(0,'DefaultAxesColorOrder',colors
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [Matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/scatter.html):

> scatter(X,Y,S,C) displays colored circles at the locations specified
>   by the vectors X and Y (which must be the same size).
>
> S determines the area of each marker (specified in points^2). S can be
>   a vector the same length as X and Y or a scalar. If S is a scalar,
>   MATLAB draws all the markers the same size. If S is empty, the default
>   size is used.
>
> C determines the color of each marker. When C is a vector the same
>   length as X and Y, the values in C are linearly mapped to the colors
>   in the current colormap. When C is a 1-by-3 matrix, it specifies the
>   colors of the markers as RGB values. If you have 3 points in the
>   scatter plot and wish to have the colors be indices into the colormap,
>   C should be a 3-by-1 matrix. C can also be a color string (see
>   ColorSpec for a list of color string specifiers).

So, for example, say that your clusters are given by the columns of the matrices X and Y, with the k'th column being the k'th cluster, X being the X coordinates, and Y being the Y coordinates. We can do what you want as follows:

```
% make some random data in clusters:
n = 15;
m = 42;
X = 0.2*rand(m,n) + repmat(rand(1,n),m,1);
Y = 0.2*rand(m,n) + repmat(rand(1,n),m,1);
% lets change the colour map:
colormap(jet);
% now plot each, one at a time, and each with a different colour:
hold on;
for k=1:n
    scatter(X(:,k),Y(:,k),40,k/n*ones(m,1));
end
```

If you don't like these colours, you can change the colormap, and if you don't like the color maps, you can, as the other answer points out, insert any RGB values you want.